# How do I swap the position of two tab pages?

Tags: vim

For example swap tab at position 2 with tab at position 3. Is there a general way of doing it?

*Position starts from 1 in the example because that is how vim lables it*

For example if I want to swap tab3 with tab2 and I am currently on tab3. I can do `:tabm 1` and it will swap it correctly.

But if I am on tab2 and I want to swap tab2 to tab3 again, `:tabm 2` doesn't do anything.

I know that in this example I could use `tabm +1` or`tabm -1` but I also want to swap over bigger ranges. Like `2` with `7`.

Comment: `tabm` does move the tab, but not swap them, to swap a tab you will have to use multiple commands (for your example `:tabm 6`, `:tabp`, `:tabm 1` *Note: It is untested*) or write a custom function. Why do you want to swap tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `a` or `n` in the values of the `mouse` option (see `:help 'mouse'`), you can simply click and drag them.